# listfield elements action

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-jde

I want to create an application,it shows some listField elements (say) Item1, Item 2 etc.
And when click on each item1 it leads to another page which also has some listfield elements 
Item11,Item12...

I am new in BB. can any one help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[**List Field Demo Link --**](http://www.blackberry.com/knowledgecenterpublic/livelink.exe/fetch/2000/348583/800332/800505/800345/How_to_-_Make_list_items_appear_on_a_screen_.html?nodeid=800616&vernum=0)

you can check the list field demo on above link it has all the details to implement listField.
Also to add navigation click you can check the onNavigationClick function

```
protected boolean navigationClick(int status, int time)
```

or may be if you want to go to next page using enter button you can override `keyDown`
function.